# Switch causes android app to terminate / java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, switch-statement

I got problems with my switch class in my Android app and I am relatively new to Java.
I'm using Eclipse with Android 4.3. The LogCat gives me this output:

```
11-30 08:29:18.296: D/AndroidRuntime(1562): Shutting down VM
11-30 08:29:18.334: W/dalvikvm(1562): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
11-30 08:29:18.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1562): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 08:29:18.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1562): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 08:29:18.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at de.madstar.asg_erfurtvertretungsplan.Vertreter$2.onClick(Vertreter.java:83)
11-30 08:29:18.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
11-30 08:29:18.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
11-30 08:29:18.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-30 08:29:18.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-30 08:29:18.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-30 08:29:18.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-30 08:29:18.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 08:29:18.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-30 08:29:18.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-30 08:29:18.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-30 08:29:18.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My App: Vertreter.java (My Remarks are in german, don't  get frightened :D ):

```
package de.madstar.asg_erfurtvertretungsplan;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Vertreter extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

public Vertreter() {
   super();
   }

public Button btnHeute;
public Button btnMorgen;
public WebView WV;
public int foo = 1;

//Teil vom Day-Checker von btnMorgen
public enum Day {
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
}
Day day;
public Vertreter(Day day) {
    this.day = day;
}




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vertreter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.vertreter, menu);

    WV = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    btnHeute = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnHeute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {...});


    btnMorgen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btnMorgen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click

            SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-");
            SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd");

            Date currentTime = new Date();


            //Prüfen ob Freitag,Samstag oder Sontag um auf Montag zu springen
            switch(day) {          
            case FRIDAY:
                foo = 3;
                break;

            case SATURDAY:
                foo = 2;
                break;

            case SUNDAY:
                foo = 1;
                break;

            case MONDAY: 
                foo = 1;
                break;

            case TUESDAY:
                foo = 1;
                break;

            case WEDNESDAY:
                foo = 1;
                break;

            case THURSDAY:
                foo = 1;
                break;
        }
            //formatter2 in integer umwandeln
            int form2 = Integer.parseInt(formatter2.format(currentTime));



            WV.loadUrl("http://schedule.asg-erfurt.de/" + formatter1.format(currentTime) + (form2 + foo));
        }
    });
    //      btnMorgen.setOnClickListener(this);



    return true;    
}

//Ab hier Optionen für dropdown menu in actionbar
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {...}

private void settingsMenuItem(){...}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Nothing, just need it to run Onclick listener for buttons

}

}
```

I dont know why my app is stopping and i tried using breakpoints to find the source but i just founded out that the problem is probably from the `switch(day) {...}`.

Comment: can you please post your full stack trace?

Comment: the problem is at line 83 of Vertreter.java, which is that line?

Comment: It is the line with:
switch(day) {          
            case FRIDAY:
                foo = 3;
                break;
...}

Answer (score 0):

you are working on a variable that is null. When you do "Day day;" you don't create an instance of Day, and I don't see any creation of Vertreter in your code so as long as you don't create an objet with a day in parameter I guess it your problem.

```
Day day;
public Vertreter(Day day) 
{
    this.day = day;
}
```

So at first call your switch is on a null reference.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: Yep. Thank you, I saw it already.
But i want to switch through the days of the Week and with my method it isnt working... Do you know how you can switch through the days of Week ?

TY MadTracki

Comment: Hum I looked on internet and your switch seems good so can you give me the new error you get without the null pointer exception ? you can also add some Log print to get more information about where your application is going.
What do you want to do with your variable foo I don't really see this ?

Comment: OK, if i set day, for example to Saturday, it is working and it skips two days to get to Monday.
And foo is just the variable how many days it should skip to get to Monday.
Thank you a lot !!

Greetings MadTracki

Comment: So you don't have anymore errors ?(except changing foo values in the switch) If so validate the answer ;)

Comment: No more Errors here :) Question can be closed. Thx @ all ^^